# Displaying Custom Images in 'tools' config options of ext.grid.panel

Tags: extjs4, panel

I am only a month old with extjs and still experimenting. My question is: I have a grid panel and within it the 'tools' config options. I am using this to enable/disable a Ext.grid.feature.Grouping variable. The 2 handler functions have the logic to disable/enable the 2 views by clicking on the 2 'cross' buttons that appear on the right side of the header. The logic is fine. However, I would like to display my set of custom images in place of the 'cross' buttons. Can this be done? If yes, how? Do I need to make some changes in the css code for that?

I have looked into the documentation and also done a good search but nothing seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 9):

Specify a custom [`type`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type) config on your tools:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
   ...
   tools: [
      {
         type: 'enable-grouping',
         handler: function() {
            ...
         }
      },
      {
         type: 'disable-grouping',
         handler: function() {
            ...
         } 
      }
   ]
});
```

Then define the following classes in a stylesheet to style your new tools:

```
.x-tool-enable-grouping {
   background-image: url('path/to/tool/image/enable-grouping.png');
}

.x-tool-disable-grouping {
   background-image: url('path/to/tool/image/disable-grouping.png');
}
```

The size of a tool image should be 15 x 15 px

Comment: Hi Russ.... Thanks for the prompt reply. I understand the logic. However, I am not clear as to where exactly I need to define the new classes? Should that be withing my project or somewhere in the extjs library? If in the library, where? Can I put it in a custom CSS file and run my project?

Comment: So, I added the type and created a css file specific to the project. In the css file I defined the two classes. I also changed the image dimensions in the sass file _tabs.scss. This makes the "cross" buttons disappear but the custom images are still not displayed in their places.
"Images" is the folder where I have put the custom images and this folder exists inside the project. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would leave the ext CSS and SASS alone and simply include a custom stylesheet after ext-all.css where you can defined your own CSS overrides. If you are having issues with getting the image to load, inspect the tool element in firebug or chrome, you can change the background-image property to find the correct path to your image.

Comment: Just use !important like this .x-tool-disable-grouping {
   background-image: url('path/to/tool/image/disable-grouping.png') !important;
}